# Unity GameObjects in Layout Group have different size on Android than Unity Gamescreen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the problem that my GameObject with the "Grid Layout Group" resizes the child GameObjects different on each device as you can see in the Screenshots below. I need them like in Screenshot 1 and 2 because the red "V" triggers the childs.

Here a picture from the GameObject with the "Grid Layout Group" the childs are in.
[image]

And here the Child Gameobjects.
[image]

Now if I install the Game on my Samsung Galaxy S8 its different like in the picture below.
[image]

Does anyone know why this happen and how to fix it?
Im not sure if this info is important but Im using a Canvas with Render Mode "Screen Space - Overlay" and Canvas Scaler "Scale With Screen Size".
[image]

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Can you please tell me which kind of scale are you using on your canvas scaler component inside your canvas game object?

Comment: Edited the Question, check Image 4.

Comment: It seems that your spacing is actually what's messing your layout. Have you tried playing with padding instead of spacing?

Comment: No. I will try it and tell you if it worked.

Comment: Tried it out. But Padding only effects the GameObject with the component itself. And not the children.